# Heroku db:migrate and faker

Tags: heroku

After `heroku rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!

no such file to load -- faker

/app/Rakefile:7

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

(in /app)*
```

I saw previous answers and I tried to shift `require 'faker'` from the first line to the line below `task :populate => :environment do` in my `sample_data.rake` file. It didn't work.

I commented `faker` in the gemfile (and it was present only in the dev environment) and I executed a `bundle install`. It didn't work.

I'm really scared about the fact that I can't use faker with heroku. Could you please help me?

Comment: If my answer below doesn't help, posting the contents of your `Gemfile` might help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is `faker` part of your production gems (outside of any groups) in your Gemfile?

**Heroku does not install `test` or `development` gems by default.**

So, you could, for example, simply change

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql'

group :development do
  gem 'faker'
end
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'faker'
```

## Alternatively...

You can **instruct Heroku to install development gems by changing the Heroku environment variable** `BUNDLE_WITHOUT`, which lists groups to *exclude*.

The default is:

```
heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
```

so you might use something like:

```
heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="test"
```

However, if your application requires the use of `faker` in its production environment, you should probably just include the gem in the default Gemfile group.

Comment: My gemfile is quite simple and the line:"gem 'faker', '0.3.1'" is under "group :development do" and not outside. According with your sentence, I tried to put it outside and it worked, Thanks very much.

Comment: @Brandon I meant to edit your answer just as a suggestion. Please feel free to revert it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

you may also
group :development do
  gem 'faker', :require=>false
end

(or)

put the require 'faker' line of you rake file to be inside the task